# Execute build task in Hudson with root privilages

Tags: security, sudo, hudson, continuous-integration

I have a build script which executes apt-get and therefore requires root privileges. What is the best way to run this script in Hudson?

Currently the only solution I have found that works is to add an entry to the sudoers file for the user hudson like so:

```
hudson  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However, although my build script now runs without error in Hudson, I am not entirely comfortable with this solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i go one further, with locking down `apt-get` i lock down what parameters you can use, because we don't want someone installing or removing something.

```
%admins         ALL =  NOPASSWD:                   \
                    /usr/bin/apt-get update,        \
                    /usr/bin/apt-get dist-upgrade,  \
                    /usr/bin/apt-get upgrade
```

which gives the group `admins` permissions to run apt-get update/dist-upgrade/upgrade without providing a password.

Comment: +1 - I didn't realize you could do that !

Answer (score 1):

You could lock down the commands that the hudson user is allowed to execute as root; change the line in your sudoers file to:

```
hudson   ALL=/usr/bin/apt-get  NOPASSWD:ALL
```

(Check the path to your apt-get binary - I'm running on Fedora so don't have that command)